# Why do I keep getting a warning: A cookie associated with a resource at http://127.0.0.1/ was set with `SameSite=None` but without `Secure`

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

Full warning message:

```
A cookie associated with a resource at http://127.0.0.1/ was set with `SameSite=None` but without `Secure`. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies marked `SameSite=None` if they are also marked `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
```

However, I set cookies like:

```
res.cookie("token", token, {httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'none', secure: true});
```

Is there a way to get rid of this warning?

Comment: secure and httpOnly both cannot be true together. Remove secure: true and it will work. Reference: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-session.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, I still get this warning

Comment: sameSite: None requires the Secure attribute in latest browser versions. See below for more information. Then can you please try removing httpOnly.

Comment: I think it will not work: A Secure cookie is only sent to the server with an encrypted request over the HTTPS protocol. Note that insecure sites (http:) can't set cookies with the Secure directive. Can you please provide your use case for which you want to send cookie with sameSite: 'none'? Have you tried CORS module?

Comment: here is c my cors config: app.use(
    cors(
      {
          credentials: true, 
          origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
      }
    )
);
app.use(cookieParser()); And btw I removed httpOnly, but still have the warning :( So, right now i set cookies like that: res.cookie("token", token, {sameSite: 'none'});

Comment: Then it is already taking care of CORS. Explicitly no need to set on Cookies.

Comment: if I don't configure sameSite the following warning pops up: <A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://127.0.0.1/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a cookie required in a third-party or cross-site context, you should set both `SameSite=None` and `Secure`, as you are doing in your original example.

First question though - do you definitely need this cookie to be cross-site? In other words, are you expecting different sites to make a request to yours that require this cookie to be sent? Examples here would be if your site is embedded within an iframe on another site, hosting images where you want to have cookies included, or creating a token for additional security on a cross-site form submission.

If not, consider `SameSite=Lax` for this cookie instead. That way it will only be sent for requests within your site.

However, when you are developing on `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` you generally do not have a certificate for a valid HTTPS connection. I would suggest, in Express, using [`app.get('env);`](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#app.settings.table) to get your current environment (`'development'` or `'production'`) and then using that to choose if you set `Secure` or not.

For example:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

if (app.get('env') !== 'development') {
  // production settings, assume HTTPS
  app.set('cookie config', { httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'lax', secure: true });
} else {
  // development settings, no HTTPS
  app.set('cookie config', { httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'lax' });
}

// Later on when setting a cookie within your route, middleware, etc.
res.cookie('token', token, app.get('cookie config'));
```

You could also set up multiple cookie configs if you have different use cases on your site.

```js
if (app.get('env') !== 'development') {
  // production settings, assume HTTPS
  app.set('cookie config 1p', { httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'lax', secure: true });
  app.set('cookie config 3p', { httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'none', secure: true });
} else {
  // development settings, no HTTPS
  app.set('cookie config 1p', { httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'lax' });
  // Assumes that I'm hosting all my test sites under localhost,
  // so the browser won't actually see them as 3p
  app.set('cookie config 3p', { httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'lax' });
}
```

You could also look up creating a self-signed certificate for your localhost environment, but that can be a bit of a pain. If you're going to do that, the effort might be better put into using some kind of container or vm for development.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks!